# error installing while "hmac" package in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pip, hmac

when iam installing HMAC package using 
    pip install hmac
command in base environment

I tried updating pip, setup tools. But all are updated to latest version. but no use.

pip install hmac

error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install hmac
Collecting hmac
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/02/14b2ade413d3f34caffadfa6ed59f3769fe108a78e34931a2cdd1762cb32/hmac-20101005.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hmac) (41.4.0)
Collecting hashlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/bb/9003d081345e9f0451884146e9ea2cff6e4cc4deac9ffd4a9ee98b318a49/hashlib-20081119.zip
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7dt9idd0\\hashlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7dt9idd0\\hashlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7dt9idd0\hashlib\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7dt9idd0\hashlib\
    Complete output (22 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
        from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
        from email._policybase import compat32
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
        from email.utils import _has_surrogates
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\email\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
        import random
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\random.py", line 46, in <module>
        from hashlib import sha512 as _sha512
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7dt9idd0\hashlib\hashlib.py", line 80
        raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
```

Comment: Strange: It seems your Python 3.7 install uses a standard library of an older python version (2.x): `raise <Exception>, <String>` is [no longer allowed in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3109/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error is because the reported line `raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"` is using syntax which is not supported in python 3.x, which raises the suspission that the module you are trying to install is not written for python 3.x but for 2.x

The module you are trying to install is [this one](https://pypi.org/project/hmac/).

The only file in the pypi project is from  06.10.2010, so almost 9 years old and checking the project description, we get:

> ## HMAC
>
> This is a stand alone packaging of the hashlib compatible hmac library
>   included with Python 2.5 so that it can be used together with the hashlib
>   backport on older versions of Python (tested on 2.4). Not needed with Python
>   2.5 or later.

So indeed, `hmac` was written with only python 2x in mind and no  updates since. You probably want to look for a different library or just use `hmac` from the [python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hmac.html) for which no additional installations are needed.